# Pipeline is not ingesting data into memsql table using procedure

Tags: apache-kafka, singlestore

I pushed the json(20 key-value pair) into the kafka and able to consume it as well - tested it to verify whether data is successfully getting pushed to kafka or not.

the following script is creating a pipeline but it's not loading data to memsql table. Do I need to modify my create pipeline script for JSON datatype.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPELINE omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline
AS LOAD DATA KAFKA '192.168.188.110:9092/ib_Omnitracs' 
INTO procedure INGEST_OMNITRACS_EVT_PROC;

DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INGEST_OMNITRACS_EVT_PROC(batch query(evt_json json))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEST(id, name) 
      SELECT evt_json::ignition,evt_json::positiontype
      FROM batch;
      ECHO SELECT 'HELLO';
END
//
DELIMITER ; 

TEST PIPELINE omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline LIMIT 5;
START PIPELINE omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline FOREGROUND LIMIT 5 BATCHES;
```

Can anyone please help what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You likely should modify your CREATE PIPELINE's AS LOAD DATA clause to perform native JSON loading, as described here: https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/load-data/#json-load-data.

There are two reasons:

- The pipeline as written will expect input from kafka to be in TSV
  format with 1 field. TSV is the default format and it infers the expected number of fields
  from the parameters to the destination stored procedure. It's actually fairly likely that input JSON records will successfully parse as such, but I wouldn't rely on this.
- It would be more performant to use the subvalue_mapping clause of a native JSON pipeline to
  extract and insert ::ignition and ::positiontype,
  skipping the overhead of a stored procedure entirely. Also, the pipeline as written will 
  instantiate temporary in-memory JSON data structures, and this is relatively 
  expensive.

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPELINE omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline
AS LOAD DATA KAFKA '192.168.188.110:9092/ib_Omnitracs' 
INTO TABLE TEST
FORMAT JSON
( 
  id <- ignition_event,
  name <- position_type
);
```

Comment: i Modified my Pipeline script with the above mentioned.Still it's not working.
0 rows affected.
>TEST PIPELINE omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline LIMIT 5;
>START PIPELINE omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline FOREGROUND LIMIT 5 BATCHES;

Comment: can you send us `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PIPELINES_CURSORS`?

Comment: DATABASE_NAME : MEMSQLDB
PIPELINE_NAME : omnitracs_gps_evt_pipeline
SOURCE_TYPE : KAFKA
SOURCE_PARTITION_ID : 0
EARLIEST_OFFSET : 0
LATEST_OFFSET : 1320
CURSOR_OFFSET : 0
SUCCESSFUL_CURSOR_OFFSET : NULL
UPDATED_UNIX_TIMESTAMP : 1549542203.604487
EXTRA_FIELDS : NULL

Answer (score 0):

ECHO SELECT is not allowed in pipeline's stored procedures.  You should have gotten an error saying so when you ran START PIPELINE ... FOREGROUND, or at CREATE PIPELINE time if the procedure was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline is working now after removing the ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG Configuration from the producer in kafka.

> ```
> CREATE PIPELINE FEB13_PIPELINE_2
> AS LOAD DATA KAFKA '192.168.188.110:9092/FEB13_PROC' 
> INTO procedure INGEST_EVT_PROC;
>
> DELIMITER //
> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INGEST_EVT_PROC(batch query(evt_json json))
> AS
> BEGIN
>     INSERT INTO TEST_FEB13(ID, NAME) 
>       SELECT evt_json::ID,evt_json::NAME
>       FROM batch;
> END
> //
> DELIMITER ;
> ```

Just one small doubt now even the double quote is getting added in the table column. How to escape it. 
JSON sent to kafka : "{'ID':1,'NAME':\'a\'}"

Comment: JSON_EXTRACT_<type> will do the needful